# change max HTTP response size google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

is there a way to change the HTTP response size limit from 33554432 bytes to, im my case, 4418142208 bytes? Its all on the local server.

Comment: You want to return 4GB from a dynamic web request? You're doing something wrong.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do this? Particularly on the dev_appserver?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the response size limit on the URL Fetch service, then [Google explicitly says no](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits).

If you're talking about outgoing data from your application, I don't know. It's not mentioned anywhere in the App Engine documentation, though, so it's probably unchangable.